# Download a file using Python without selenium like Chrome's "Save Link As"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, python-requests, urllib2

There is a [web page](https://www.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date=01-12-2003&section=EQ) where I can download zip files using "Save Link As" option in chrome but when I copy [link address](https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2001/JAN/cm01JAN2001bhav.csv.zip) and open that in the browser it returns 403/forbidden. I tried to save the file using requests library but it also gets forbidden response.

I don't know how chrome can download it but I can't download using requests library.

How can I download the file without using selenium web driver as that will be overkill for this simple task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using requests for this. Simple example below with the first file filled in:

```
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2003/DEC/cm01DEC2003bhav.csv.zip'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', 'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/'}
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
open('cm01DEC2003bhav.csv.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

The website checks for referer in the header, if referer doesn't match with the website itself it denies the request.

Comment: The above worked for me. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Did you check the status code of your request? If you check it will be 403 and you won't be able to open the zip file even if it is downloaded as nothing is in there

Comment: It's what I get for not checking r.content before writing a blank zip file. You're correct. I'm working on an edit to my original script to see if I can get you to the finish line.

Comment: I tried so many things but not working. Still getting 403 response

Comment: Is there a requirement that states you can not use Selenium?

Comment: I think the server blocked both wget and curl

Comment: @Douglas there isn't any such requirement but I don't want to use selenium for this simple task as that will make the process slow. I am curious how it is possible from chrome and only when clicking the link and not when copying the url in the browser.

Comment: I think you may need to pass a cookie back to the site. Try using sessions, I'll be able to hop back on shortly to try again.

Comment: I checked developer console and found that this website doesn't store any cookie in the browser

Comment: @Douglas The website checks for referer in the header, if referer doesn't match with the website itself it denies the request. I added Referer in the header and it worked

Comment: @JagjeetSingh we need to add referer to website itself in the header

Comment: I see, I approved the edit to the code block above. Glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Good answer but I don't think he needs a third-party library for this. `urllib.request` handles this perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `urllib.request.urlretrieve` with a custom `Referer` header like @Douglas specified:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
>>> opener.addheaders = [('Referer', 'https://www.nseindia.com/')]
>>> urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
>>> source = 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2001/JAN/cm01JAN2001bhav.csv.zip'
>>> destination = 'destination.csv.zip'  # Path to destination.
>>> urllib.request.urlretrieve(source, destination)
('destination.csv.zip', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x10ce20208>)
```

This will download your file to the specified file path.

[image: File downloaded]